# Query too complex

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to move some calculations out of Excel into my Access database but i am faced with the 'Query too complex' error when i use above 5 input values. Should i split the query up or is there a more efficient way of working around this?? Any help would be appreciated! Here is the code:

```
SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.Assetname, qb1.Year,
      ((qb1.DatapointValue*1000000)+qb2.DatapointValue+
        qb3.DatapointValue+qb4.DatapointValue+qb5.DatapointValue+
        qb6.DatapointValue) AS MPPOilRevised

FROM ((((((PEBaseQuery AS qb1 
INNER JOIN PEBaseQuery AS qb2 ON qb1.AssetName=qb2.AssetName) 
INNER JOIN PEBaseQuery AS qb3 ON qb1.AssetName=qb3.AssetName) 
INNER JOIN PEBaseQuery AS qb4 ON qb1.AssetName=qb4.AssetName) 
INNER JOIN PEBaseQuery AS qb5 ON qb1.AssetName=qb5.AssetName) 
INNER JOIN PEBaseQuery AS qb6 ON qb1.AssetName=qb6.AssetName))

WHERE qb1.DatapointID=2003 And qb2.DatapointID=2032 
      And qb3.DatapointID=2034 And qb4.DatapointID=2042 
      And qb5.DatapointID=2036 And qb6.DatapointID=2030;
```

---

```
CompanyName, Year, AssetName, DatapointID, DatapointName,   DatapointValue 
CompanyA,    2011, CAAsset1,  2005,        OIL,             170883.740972926 
CompanyA,    2011, CAAsset1,  2032,        Wellwork,        615913 
CompanyA,    2011, CAAsset1,  2034,        Annual shutdown, 0 
CompanyA,    2011, CAAsset1,  2042,        Export,          0 
CompanyA,    2011, CAAsset1,  2036,        Plant,           958387 
CompanyA,    2011, CAAsset1,  2030,        Reservoir,       2394231
```

Comment: Try flattening out the `qbX.DatapointValue` operands into `(SELECT qbX.DatapointValue FROM ... WHERE.... ) AS ExprX`.

Comment: Some separate question .. why do you need this multiplying to 1000000 for the first DatapointValue? It looks very strange, since the values are from one column. I think there is the way to make the whole query much more simpler without it.

Comment: the multiplying by a million is because i need the value per Million Barrels of Oil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need an aggregation query, instead of this complex one. E.g.

```
select companyName, assetName, year, 
   Sum(DatapointValue) as MPPOilRevised
from PEBaseQuery 
where DatapointID in (2032, 2034, 2042, 2036)
group by companyName, assetName, year
```

The only issue is multiplying to 1000000 for the first Data Point. You could try `IIF` for that:

```
select companyName, assetName, year, 
   Sum(IIf(DatapointID=2003,DatapointValue*1000000,DatapointValue)) as MPPOilRevised
from PEBaseQuery 
where DatapointID in (2032, 2034, 2042, 2036)
group by companyName, assetName, year
```

Also please try such 'crazy' query, with sub query for this particular DatapointID, without `IIF`:

```
select companyName, assetName, year, SUM(DatapointValue) 
        + (select SUM(DatapointValue * 1000000) from  PEBaseQuery q2 
           where q2.companyName = q1.companyName 
              and q2.assetName= q1.assetName
              and q2.year= q1.year
              and q2.DatapointID = 2003
           group by companyName, assetName, year)
    from PEBaseQuery q1
    where DatapointID in (2032, 2034, 2042, 2036)
    group by companyName, assetName, year
```

Update for 'Production Max Potential'. Please try following:

```
select b.companyName, b.assetName, IIf(b.calculationResult > mp.calculationResult,b.calculationResult,mp.calculationResult)  as MPPOilRevised
from 
    (select companyName, assetName, year, Sum(IIf(DatapointID=2003,DatapointValue*1000000,DatapointValue)) as calculationResult
        from PEBaseQuery 
        where DatapointID in (2032, 2034, 2042, 2036) 
        group by companyName, assetName, year) b --Base
     left join 
     (select companyName, assetName, year, 
        Sum(DatapointValue) as calculationResult
        from PEBaseQuery 
        where DatapointID = 2218
        group by companyName, assetName, year) mp -- Max Potential
    on b.companyName= mp.companyName
        and b.assetName = mp.assetName
        and b.year = mp.year
```

Example of calculation with substract logic. **Updated** with final crazy SQL. Please also note that I would go with application logic or stored procedures for such kind of things:

```
    select b.companyName, b.assetName, IIf(b.calculationResult > mp.calculationResult,b.calculationResult,mp.calculationResult)  as MPPOilRevised
from 
    (select companyName, assetName, year, SUM(DatapointValue) 
        + (select SUM(DatapointValue * 1000000) from  PEBaseQuery q2 
           where q2.companyName = q1.companyName 
              and q2.assetName= q1.assetName
              and q2.year= q1.year
              and q2.DatapointID = 2003
           group by companyName, assetName, year)
        - (select SUM(DatapointValue) from  PEBaseQuery q2 
           where q2.companyName = q1.companyName 
              and q2.assetName= q1.assetName
              and q2.year= q1.year
              and q2.DatapointID = 2029 
           group by companyName, assetName, year)
    from PEBaseQuery q1
    where DatapointID in (2032, 2034, 2042, 2036)
    group by companyName, assetName, year) b --Base
     left join 
     (select companyName, assetName, year, 
        Sum(DatapointValue) as calculationResult
        from PEBaseQuery 
        where DatapointID = 2218
        group by companyName, assetName, year) mp -- Max Potential
    on b.companyName= mp.companyName
        and b.assetName = mp.assetName
        and b.year = mp.year
```

Comment: You could add in an IIf for the multiplication, I reckon.

Comment: I tried the above code with the correction (DatapointID = '2003', DatapointValue*1000000, DatapointValue) but it says 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression'

Comment: It should read `Sum(IIf(DatapointID=2003,DatapointValue*1000000,DatapointValue)) AS `

Comment: Updated according with this correction, thx. Also added one more variant, similar works fine for Oracle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help! Both versions work :) I might be pushing my luck here but i have another question.. I need to incorporate this in an IF statement to say, If the DatapointValue of DatapointID 2218 (Max production potential) is LESS THAN the result of the above calculation, then MPPOilRevised = the calculated value, otherwise MPPOilRevised = The value of 2218

Comment: It is become to complex for one query, I would use separate query + join.

Comment: it seems to work perfectly, no errors. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: What would be the appropriate syntax if i wanted to subtract the value of another datapoint with the ID 2029 from the main calculation? (to removed market value losses)

Comment: You can update third query with one more sub query (with minus and 2029 ID instead of plus and 2003 ID). I can post one more code snippet if required.

Comment: I wrote the same code for subtraction however i was unsure how to combine this with the IF statements in the Production Max Potential code snippet

Comment: Take a look on latest update. And maybe post next issue (if any :)) to separate question, since there are already too many comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ive posted a couple new questions, if you could take a look that would be great as im sure you'll understand the context better than others (having already helped me so much!)